# How to convert a method name into a String

Tags: objective-c, methods

I´m developing a little game right now and I want to have several levels.
So i´m asking if it´s the first time the app gets launched. If it´s like that the user will start at level1.
But if now i want to start another method.
I have methods like:

```
-(void)level1{};
-(void)level2{};
```

.
.
.
till level 100 or so.
So after if got the amount of times the app got started i want to call a method, which fits.
So i tried to make it like:

```
[self [NSString stringWithString:@"level%d", level]];
```

Because "level" has a number like 1,2,3...,100. So i tried to make it like level1,level2, level3, and so on.
But for that I get an error -> Unexpected interface name 'NSString': expected expression.
Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance!
Peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSSelectorFromString()`:

```
NSString* methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d", level];
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
[self performSelector:sel];
```